# What does "SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:2532)" mean using the Python ssl library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, ssl-certificate, python-asyncio

I am trying to use connect to another party using Python 3 asyncio module and get this error:

```
     36     sslcontext = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
---> 37     sslcontext.load_cert_chain(cert, keyfile=ca_cert)
     38

SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:2532)
```

The question is just what the error mean. My certificate is correct, *the keyfile (CA certificate) might not*.

Comment: You do mention that the key -file might not be correct. Cert loading will fail if the cert (public key) does not go with the right private key file.

Comment: You have `keyfile=ca_cert`, which seems likely to be incorrect (or you have chosen horrible variable names).  Does your `ca_cert` really contain a private key?

Comment: @larsks How choosing horrible variable names can cause errors in the code? Any suggestions (or convention) on how to name them? The ca_cert file begins with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`, what seems to be a valid encrypted key, and ends with `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`. Should header and footer say something different?

Comment: That is an SSL certificate, not an SSL private key file.  You want the private key that corresponds to your local certificate.

Comment: @larsks If I am the client connecting to a server, wouldn't I need their _public key_ instead?

Comment: People that down vote a question should at least leave a comment at to why, and maybe even how to improve the question.

Comment: I've rolled back the last revision here since answers shouldn't be edited into the question.

Comment: Important information for https noobs: the certfile parameter for load_cert_chain is a public key created by the certificate authority after signing, and is NOT the certificate request file

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Assuming that version 3.6 is being used:

See: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Modules/_ssl.c#L3523-L3534

```
 PySSL_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS_S(pw_info.thread_state);
 r = SSL_CTX_check_private_key(self->ctx);
 PySSL_END_ALLOW_THREADS_S(pw_info.thread_state);
 if (r != 1) { 
    _setSSLError(NULL, 0, __FILE__, __LINE__);
    goto error;
 }
```

What it is saying is that `SSL_CTX_check_private_key` failed; thus, the private key is not correct.

Reference to the likely version:

- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.4/Modules/_ssl.c#L2529-L2535

Comment: Agreed. You went to the source and found the right answer.

Comment: I read it before but had no clue of what that meant. I think it is using _openssl_ (on Unix systems) and reporting the error it got at system level. That explains why the error would generate from that line in the source, right?

Answer (score 21):

In your code, you are calling:

```
sslcontext.load_cert_chain(cert, keyfile=ca_cert)
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext):

> Load a private key and the corresponding certificate. The certfile
>   string must be the path to a single file in PEM format containing the
>   certificate as well as any number of CA certificates needed to
>   establish the certificate’s authenticity. The keyfile string, if
>   present, must point to a file containing the private key in. Otherwise
>   the private key will be taken from certfile as well. See the
>   discussion of Certificates for more information on how the certificate
>   is stored in the certfile.

Based on the name of the arguments in your example, it looks like you are passing a CA certificate to the `keyfile` argument.  That is incorrect, you need to pass in the private key that was used to generate your local certificate (otherwise the client cannot use your certificate).  A private key file will look something like:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,9BA4973008F0A0B36FBE1426C198DD1B

...data...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

You only need the CA certificate if you are trying to verify the validity of SSL certificates that have been signed by this certificate.  In that case, you would probably use `SSLContext.load_verify_locations()` to load the CA certificate (although I have not worked with the SSL module recently, so don't take my word on that point).

Comment: I received the same error and I only need the certificate chain verified. The private key is not relevant so this answer helps as it explained that my ansible script is looking for a private key but should be set to only look for the certificate chain.

Answer (score 9):

The error means a private key file is missing.
Generate a key pair in openssl shell:
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365

Start Python SSL Server:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, 
             SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

import ssl

httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 4443), 
                           SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)

httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(httpd.socket, 
                 certfile='/tmp/cert.pem',keyfile='
                           /tmp/key.pem', server_side=True)

httpd.serve_forever()
```

(We use port 4443 so that I can run the tests as normal user; the usual port 443 requires root privileges).

Answer (score 4):

In my case, this error meant that my certificate had the wrong file extension. I had to convert my `cert.der` file to a `cert.pem` file using the below:

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in cert.der -out cert.pem
```

Comment: It wasn’t the extension that was wrong, the file format as wrong and you had to convert the file to the pem format.

Answer (score 1):

Upon using openssl to generate a self-signed certificate protected with password I faced a similar issue where I got the following output:

```
ontext.load_cert_chain(certfile= certificate_private, keyfile= certificate)
ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:4012)
```

After reading twice to understand the documentation on [load_cert_chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.load_cert_chain) I came up with the following solution:

```py
import ssl
    
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
context.load_cert_chain(certfile= certificate_private, keyfile= certificate_key, password= certificate_password)

connection = http.client.HTTPSConnection(host, port=443, context=context)
connection.request(method="POST", url=request_url, headers=request_headers, body=json.dumps(request_body_dict))
response = connection.getresponse()
```

Where the certfile is the `cert.pem`
the keyfile is the `key.pem` 
and the password is the one I used when I generated the self-signed certificate similar as stated [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62665240/5783883).