# Python requests [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:2603)

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, ssl-certificate, python-requests

while trying to do a requests call on a in-house web-service, I am getting the following error message, whereas I have put in the PEM certificate file and have specified it
    r = requests.get(url, cert=cert)

and the error response I get is

```
raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:2603)
```

I dont have access to export the private key for personal certificate which might help in resolving this issue. Is there any other way to bypass it or point it to the certificate and provide authentication?
The url opens up in browser from my computer totally fine without asking for user credentials or anything for authorization.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "SSLError: \[SSL\] PEM lib (\_ssl.c:2532)" mean using the Python ssl library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109449/what-does-sslerror-ssl-pem-lib-ssl-c2532-mean-using-the-python-ssl-libr)

Comment: you are probably right, but actually I dont have the access to export private for my personal computer's certificate. Can there be any other way to point it to my local certificate so it handles the private key and the authentication and authorization?

Comment: Sorry my bad I missed the `python-2.7` tag, if you look at [https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Modules/_ssl.c#L2595](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Modules/_ssl.c#L2595) you'll see the exception is raised from the `_password_callback()` function, which would suggest that your cert is password protected and you have to supply that password.

Comment: Thanks man! so I can provide my domain credentials to this function along with the certificate? would you be able to help me with that?

Comment: See [this feature request](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/1573) on Github - if I'm not mistaken, it's not (and probably will not be) implemented, I'm afraid.

Comment: so I would have to move to v3.3 to get this working? do you think there might be any other turn around way for this to work?

Comment: Maybe just use pycurl as per [this comment](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/1573#issuecomment-169916326) instead of requests?

Comment: the thing is I dont have the private key, but do have the credentials. pycurl is asking for the private key.