# SSLError in Python requests module

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I would like to authenticate to server from my client using certificate that is generated from server.I have a server-ca.crt and below is the CURL command that is working.How to send similar request using python requests module .

```
$ curl -X GET -u sat_username:sat_password \
-H "Accept:application/json" --cacert katello-server-ca.crt \
https://satellite6.example.com/katello/api/organizations
```

I have tried following way and it is getting some exception, can someone help in resolving this issue.

```
 python requestsCert.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requestsCert.py", line 2, in <module>
    res=requests.get('https://satellite6.example.com/katello/api/organizations', cert='/certificateTests/katello-server-ca.crt', verify=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 68, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 464, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 431, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:2554)
```

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109449/what-does-sslerror-ssl-pem-lib-ssl-c2532-mean-using-the-python-ssl-libr but I'm not sure that's a duplicate since in this question, the error is raised in `requests` code, whereas in the other question, `requests` is not involved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
res=requests.get('https://...', cert='/certificateTests/katello-server-ca.crt', verify=True)
```

The `cert` argument in `requests.get` is used to specify the client certificate and key which should be used for mutual authentication. It is not used to specify the trusted CA as the `--cacert` argument in curl does. Instead you should use the `verify` argument:

```
res=requests.get('https://...', verify='/certificateTests/katello-server-ca.crt')
```

For more information see [SSL Cert Verification](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification) and [Client Side Certificates](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#client-side-certificates) in the documentation for `requests`.