# How to fix the issue : context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile) ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3837)

Tags: python, macos, flask, operating-system

This issue was during configuring the 2-way ssl for flask restful application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "SSLError: \[SSL\] PEM lib (\_ssl.c:2532)" mean using the Python ssl library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109449/what-does-sslerror-ssl-pem-lib-ssl-c2532-mean-using-the-python-ssl-libr)