# what [SSL] PEM Lib <_ssl.c:3932> mean for python Flask ssl?

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to run flask with godaddy ssl certificate on local windows server but keeps throwing _ssl.c:3932 error. Using the private key generated from the server which was used to generate the certificate . Currently, just testing on the built in development server.

Wondering if anyone has a resolution for the issue? Thank you

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2) 
    context.load_cert_chain('c3_combo.crt', 'web.key')
    app.run_server(debug=False, port=8000, host='0.0.0.0', ssl_context=context)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ins_query3_w_cert.py", line 661, in <module>
    context.load_cert_chain('c3_combo.crt', 'web.key')
ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3932)
```

Comment: Please post full stack trace. Are you using the built-in development server' Wsgi? Nginx? Gunicorn?

Comment: no, just testing on the development server first. Thanks

Comment: can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Here is the traceback you meant that??

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "ins_query3_w_cert.py", line 661, in <module>
    context.load_cert_chain('c3_combo.crt', 'web.key')
ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3932)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109449/what-does-sslerror-ssl-pem-lib-ssl-c2532-mean-using-the-python-ssl-libr