# Error [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:4022) when using Paho for MQTT TLS

Tags: python, ssl, mqtt, paho

I am trying to connect my MQTT Broker using Paho library. But now I am stucking with this error. My code is below:

```
import os
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import ssl
from configparser import ConfigParser
.....
    try:
        publishInfo = {
            "parking": "test"
        }
        config = ConfigParser()
        config.read('config.ini')
        ipAddressMQTT = config['MQTT']['ipaddress']
        port = config['MQTT']['port']
        auth = {
            'username': config['MQTT']['username'],
            'password': config['MQTT']['password']
        }
        tls = {
            'ca_certs': config['MQTT']['cakeypath'],
            'certfile': config['MQTT']['certKeyPath'],
            'keyfile': config['MQTT']['clientkeypath'],
            'tls_version': ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1
        }
        
        publish.single(topic='parkingStatus', payload=publishInfo, retain=True, hostname=ipAddressMQTT, port=port, keepalive=60, auth=auth, tls=tls, protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311, transport='tcp')
    except Exception as e:
        self.showMessage(QMessageBox.Critical, "Error...", "Error "+str(e), "Error ")
```

and my config.ini file looks like:

```
[MQTT]
ipaddress = 172.18.0.3
port = 8883
username = parking
password = public
cakeypath = /home/atn/Documents/IUK/Abschlussarbeit/emqx_mqtt_cert/ca.pem
clientkeypath = /home/atn/Documents/IUK/Abschlussarbeit/emqx_mqtt_cert/parkingspot.pem
certkeypath = /home/atn/Documents/IUK/Abschlussarbeit/emqx_mqtt_cert/parkingspot.csr

[Geofence]
ipaddress = 172.18.0.4
port = 9851
```

The certificate was generated with the following commands:

```
openssl genrsa -out parkingspot.key 2048
openssl req -new -key parkingspot.key -out parkingspot.csr -subj "/C=DE/ST=NRW/L=Dortmund/O=EMQX/CN=client"
openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in parkingspot.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out parkingspot.pem
```

After trying for hours, I decided to ask you guys. Give me a hand, pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll guess based on the field names (which at best are confusing) that the values should be

```
cakeypath = /.../ca.pem
clientkeypath = /.../parkingspot.key
certkeypath = /.../parkingspot.pem
```

Answer (score 2):

In your config file you have:

```
certkeypath = /home/atn/Documents/IUK/Abschlussarbeit/emqx_mqtt_cert/parkingspot.csr
```

A `csr` file is generally a Certificate Signing Request (the request you send to a CA asking for a certificate to be issued). I would expect the file used here to have a `.key` extension (this does assume you used the standard extensions when creating the certificate).

More info can be found in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109449/what-does-sslerror-ssl-pem-lib-ssl-c2532-mean-using-the-python-ssl-libr).

Comment: I changed to .key file but it repeated same error.

Comment: You would need to provide more info (i.e. how you generated the key/certificate); as per the linked question the error relates to an invalid key.

Comment: I used these following commands to generate client key and certificate: openssl genrsa -out parkingspot.key 2048, openssl req -new -key parkingspot.key -out parkingspot.csr -subj "/C=DE/ST=NRW/L=Dortmund/O=EMQX/CN=client", openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in parkingspot.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out parkingspot.pem. Is that what you need?

Comment: Please amend your question when adding detail rather than posting code in the comments. See @hardillb's answer (I had not noticed that the param 'certfile' is being pulled from the 'certKeyPath' in your config - as he says this is quite confusing because its a certificate not a key!).