# In Python flask what does ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3563) mean?

Tags: https

```py
import ssl
context = ssl.create_default_context()

context.load_cert_chain('cert.pem', 'key.pem')
```

Both the cert and key files are matching as checked in another website
But I am getting :
`context.load_cert_chain('cert.pem', 'key.pem') ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3563)`

Running a Python Flask app using ssl certificates given by the domain keepers godaddy.
I am expected to run the app in https.

Comment: This depends on the Python version used. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109449/what-does-sslerror-ssl-pem-lib-ssl-c2532-mean-using-the-python-ssl-libr has a similar problem where the private key was not correct but had `_ssl.c:2532` as the error row in Python 3.6